# Draw a logical circuit python

Tags: python-3.x, boolean-expression, circuit

I am trying to make a code that it will take as input a boolean expression like: " A && B || C" and it will draw the logical circuit as output. The programming language that i used is python. Can you suggest me any program or library that I can use to succeed this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try SchemDraw

http://www.collindelker.com/wp/2014/08/electrical-schematic-drawing-python/

It has logic gates support. You will still need to parse the input yourself.

Comment: Broken link unfortunately